# Torsion in homology groups of a topological space

Tags: algebraic-topology

It seems as though "nice" spaces don't have torsion in their homology groups. What is the underlying characteristic of these nice spaces; that they can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$? So what are some examples of spaces which can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but have torsion in their homology groups?

Comment: If by "spaces" you mean "compact surfaces"...

Comment: Are you implying the real projective plane is somewhat unnice?! :)

Comment: If you want to restrict your attention to subsets of $\mathbb R^3$, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4478/torsion-in-homology-or-fundamental-group-of-subsets-of-euclidean-3-space is quite relevant. In particular, for sensible subsets there is no torsion.

Comment: Dear user, Just as a pedagogical comment: the apparent phenomenon of homology of "nice" spaces being torsion free is just a reflection of the fact that the first examples one sees are low-dimensional, or very simple spaces such as spheres.  It's worth noting that already compact three manifolds will very often have torsion in their $H_1$.  Regards,

Comment: If $G$ is any group, then there is a $2$-dimensional cell complex $X$ with $\pi_1(X) \cong G$; and then $H_1(X)$ is isomorphic to $G$ made abelian. So, as Mariano asks, are these spaces not nice?

Comment: @RonnieBrown : does a 2-dimensional cell complex corresponding to $G=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ embed in $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^3$?